# New Relic on Server 2012 Stops reporting Data

Tags: newrelic, windows-server-2012-r2

Fist time on this forum I have installed NR on Server2012 machines and it reports data for first few hours then you can not see any data on the portal. We go back to servers and confirm that service is running, NR agent is also running but data does not seem to be reported. If i restart the new relic service data start to show up again but disappears after couple of hours.
In same network I have Linux machines they work absoultely fine.

Any help will be appreciated. (I am Using the free version)

Answer (score 1):

We'd like to make sure that you are have the necessary Windows Updates that our server monitor depends on. As I'm sure you're aware, Microsoft releases General Distribution Releases (GDRs) as part of Windows Updates. Our server monitor requires .NET 4 to be patched up to a certain level, and one of the GDRs that MS pushed was a fix that we require for the Windows Server Monitor to run correctly. This article references a download that includes the fix that we require: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871.

Although using Windows Update is the recommended way to fix this issue, you do have the option of just installing this specific fix on the affected system rather than installing all of the recommended updates.

There is something more that we want to verify with you, please make sure that you have installed the full 4.0 Framework or higher. Because for default the installer just installed the Client Profile.Example for .Net framework k 4.0:

1.) Look in the installed programs list in Control Panel.

2.) You will see both Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile and Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Extended. If there is only the Client Profile, please make sure install the Extended.